# Querying XML data from a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I've tried every suggestion on the SO threads related to this topic, but still not getting what I need. I have an XML column named `SC`. This is on SQL Server 2014 (in case it matters). There is only one row in the table, and the XML data in column `SC` contains the following snippet...

```
<SC_ROOT>
  <COMPONENTS>
    <COMPONENT>
      <NAME>Status A Detection</NAME>
      <PROPERTIES>
        <COMP_ENABLED>True</COMP_ENABLED>
      </PROPERTIES>
    </COMPONENT>
    ...
  </COMPONENTS>
</SC_ROOT>
```

I would like to return a table with `<NAME>` and `<COMP_ENABLED>` for only those items where the `<NAME>` contains "Detection". If there is already a good example of this please point me to it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to return only the XML where the name contains Detection, or do you want to shred that XML into a table?

Comment: I want to return the values without the XML.  So that would be something like:  'Status A Detection','True'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    Name = xc.value('(NAME)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    CompEnabled = xc.value('(PROPERTIES/COMP_ENABLED)[1]', 'varchar(10)')
FROM 
    dbo.YourTable
CROSS APPLY
    SC.nodes('/SC_ROOT/COMPONENTS/COMPONENT') AS XT(XC)
WHERE
    xc.value('(NAME)[1]', 'varchar(50)') LIKE '%Detection'
```

The `.nodes()` call bascially returns a "virtual table" with a table alias `XT` which has one column (alias `XC`) that contains the XML fragment that corresponds to the XPath expression - basically the `<COMPONENT>` XML fragment. You reach into that to extract the detailed info you need

**Update:** if your XML looks like this:

```
<COMPONENT>
  <NAME>Status A Detection</NAME>
  <PROPERTIES NAME="COMP_ENABLED" VALUE="True" />
</COMPONENT>
```

then use this code to get the results:

```
SELECT
    Name = xc.value('(NAME)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    CompEnabled = xc.value('(PROPERTIES[@NAME="COMP_ENABLED"]/@VALUE)[1]', 'varchar(10)')
FROM 
    dbo.YourTable
CROSS APPLY
    SC.nodes('/SC_ROOT/COMPONENTS/COMPONENT') AS XT(XC)
WHERE
    xc.value('(NAME)[1]', 'varchar(50)') LIKE '%Detection'
```

Comment: I'm looking to return all of the component entries which have a name that ends with "Detection" and the corresponding "comp_enabled" column value.  Some will be "true" and some "false".

Comment: @Skatterbrainz: that's what my answer is doing - or not??

Comment: I would think so, but I'm getting no results when I run it.  What would be the code to just dump all of the <NAME> nodes as a column of values?

Comment: @Skatterbrainz: just remove the second item from the `SELECT`

Comment: Bingo!  That gets me closer.  Still working on the property set

Comment: I think I see the problem.  I stated <PROPERTY><COMP_ENABLED>, but it's actually <PROPERTY NAME="COMP_ENABLED" VALUE="True" />

Answer (score 2):

So assuming that `COMPONENT` can repeat, and you want to just select the `COMPONENT` nodes where `NAME LIKE '%Detection%'`, the following should work:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = '<SC_ROOT>
  <COMPONENTS>
    <COMPONENT>
      <NAME>Status A Detection</NAME>
      <PROPERTIES>
        <COMP_ENABLED>True</COMP_ENABLED>
      </PROPERTIES>
    </COMPONENT>  
    <COMPONENT>
      <NAME>Status B Other</NAME>
      <PROPERTIES>
        <COMP_ENABLED>True</COMP_ENABLED>
      </PROPERTIES>
    </COMPONENT>  
    <COMPONENT>
      <NAME>Status C Detection</NAME>
      <PROPERTIES>
        <COMP_ENABLED>True</COMP_ENABLED>
      </PROPERTIES>
    </COMPONENT>    
  </COMPONENTS>
</SC_ROOT>'

SELECT X.Component.query('.')
FROM @xml.nodes('/SC_ROOT/COMPONENTS/COMPONENT') as X(Component)
WHERE CAST(x.Component.query('NAME/text()') AS NVARCHAR(100)) LIKE '%Detection%'
```

output:

```
<COMPONENT><NAME>Status A Detection</NAME><PROPERTIES><COMP_ENABLED>True</COMP_ENABLED></PROPERTIES></COMPONENT>
<COMPONENT><NAME>Status C Detection</NAME><PROPERTIES><COMP_ENABLED>True</COMP_ENABLED></PROPERTIES></COMPONENT>
```

That will get you the raw XML fragments.  If you want to shred that down to a table, you'd have to modify the columns you're selecting and the `.query()` in the `SELECT`.   This will work no matter how many times `NAME` repeats in a single `COMPONENT`, as long as at least one  has the word `'Detection'` in it.

If `NAME` can only occur once, or you only care about the first instance, you could also do:

```
SELECT X.Component.query('.')
FROM @xml.nodes('/SC_ROOT/COMPONENTS/COMPONENT[contains(NAME[1], "Detection")]') as X(Component)
```

Which would give the same output.